# Difference in protocol filter output Wireshark tshark

Tags: protocols, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I am working with Wireshark and tshark (slightly advanced beginner with both) to dissect and filter a lot of pcap files. One of my interests is to filter out certain protocols into text files that I can ingest into a database for aggregate analysis. I am doing this using tshark with a `bash` file:

```
for pcap_file in "${pcap_file_folder}\*.pcap";
do
    tshark -r "${file}" -2 -R smtp -T fields -E sep=/t -E header=y -E quote=d ...<etc>
done
```

The "etc" part of this code is just a list of field names that I want to retain (e.g., `-e ip.src -e smtp.message`).

As I was looking at the "smtp" filtered files this morning, I decided to check to see if Wireshark might provide more information on some of the packets that looked interesting. So, I opened the relevant `.pcap` file in Wireshark and filtered for `smtp`. I got back 30 results, while in tshark the same file produced over 150k results. What is the difference between the `-R` filter in tshark versus the filter in Wireshark? Is there one that is preferable?

I also noticed in the file resulting from the tshark filter that the `frame.protocols` field often did not contain "smtp". Am I using `-R` incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `-R`  with `-Y`?  (i.e., using a display filter instead of a read filter)